# Заполнение массива в цикле foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

чуть-чуть глупый вопрос.

Пытаюсь заполнить массив выборкой из БД таким образом:

```
foreach ($sql_student as $key) {
    $students = array($k => array("name" => $key['name'],"id" => $key['id']));
$k++;
}
```

$sql_student содержит следующее:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["name"]=>
    string(44) "Иванов"
    ["groupp"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Кекк"
    ["groupp"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "лал"
    ["groupp"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

соответственно, когда записываю в массив $students, то каждый раз он перезаписывается и остается только последняя запись.
Уже глаза не видят, где я не так сделал. Помогите, пожалуйста:)

Comment: $students[] = [
 "name" => $key['name'],
 "id" => $key['id']
];

Comment: @tcpack4 создайте ответ, отмечу Ваш ответ правильным. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: вариант - `$students = array_map(function($v){ unset($v['groupp']); return $v;}, $sql_student);` но нужно ли вам вообще делать почти клон массива? одним полем меньше, одним больше, разве что вы его сериализовать куда нибудь будете.

Comment: @teran да, для сериализации как-раз

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в каждом шаге пересоздаете массив заново. Инициализируйте пустой массив перед циклом.
Собственно как-то так:

```
$students = [];
foreach ($sql_student as $key) {
  $students[$k] = [
    "name" = $key['name'],
    "id" = $key['id']
  ];
  $k++;
}
```